# Wearable body gear that automatically evokes video effects during editing?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, editing

Consider an arm-cast device programmed to connect with, or be detected by, video editing software during post-production, for the application of video effects wherever the device appears in frame.

If someone in the video wears the arm cast, is filmed wearing it, and the video shoot finishes and recording is stopped, can the video editing software like Adobe Premiere Pro connect to or identify that device within the film, and apply some pre-set special effects to it in each video frame the arm cast appears?

Do wearable clothes or devices recognizable by video editing software exist like this? If so, link some examples

Comment: Premiere is not the type of software you’d use for this sort of thing. Cinema4D supports object tracking for 3D postproduction, and I’m sure other 3D apps do too.  But that’s offline, POSTproduction. The hot trend now is doing it real-time. Viacom is a big name in motion capture. Unreal Engine and Unity are big for real-time virtual environments, which can be combined with camera tracking, and possibly also object tracking. Houdini is good at creating procedural geometry to run on UE or Unity.

Comment: As far as wearable goes, most trackers for 3D match moving are retroreflective spheres, about the size of a marble, that get fastened to the objects you want to track. With Viacom systems, the balls reflect infrared light that doesn’t interfere with the visible spectrum that other cameras on set are recording.

Comment: could you provide a sample link to these reotroreflective spheres?

Comment: https://optitrack.com/accessories/markers/

Comment: are any $1,500 and under video camcorders compatible with Optitrack markers? or this is exclusively hollywood property

Comment: There's a "hand kit" at the bottom of the page, which is like a pair of gloves for the markers.  Since you asked about an arm-cast device, maybe that's close?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that the off-the-shelf stuff is mostly expensive, but it hasn't stopped Do-it-Yourselfers, makers, engineers, and tech-savvy people from coming up with homegrown solutions.  This is a small VFX boutique of four young people who developed a pretty good system:   www.hivedivision.net and in this video of their work, you can tell that they use BlackMagic pocket cinema cameras.  The 4K model is in that price range.  https://youtu.be/ysIOi_MP_cs

Comment: real aim is a face blurring mask, which means that The Avengers baring balls have to be worn on the face? are these as well accessible to amateurs and their software?

Comment: You don’t need all that if you don’t need to do it real-time. If you can record it and then sit down and work on it for a month, you can do it in cinema4D. I’m not sure about blender or maya, but probably those too. For C4D, you don’t need the markers, but you do need a rigid piece of geometry in the real world of which you know the exact dimensions, and a matching 3D model of it. So, if you make a solid mask, that would work fine. C4D is lauded for its ease of use, but that doesn’t mean that it’s easy. Consider hiring someone who knows it, but don’t be afraid to give it a shot, either.

Comment: This video shows the actor drawing dots on his face before editing the footage in cinema4D. Can tracking effects be applied post-production even without drawing dots beforehand? If not, how is that drawing dots work in lieu of Optitrack's baring ball markers? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj5H6-xuqqw

Comment: The Viacom systems that use dots use multiple cameras to triangulate the exact 3D location of the markers, which is useful when you need to be very precise.  Drawn dots help with single-camera photogrammetric approaches which use automatic point trackers to "latch on" to an image.  The drawn dots aren't strictly necessary if the image contains enough texture/contrast/detail, and there isn't much motion or lens blur.  Some trackers, like Fusion are good without dots, but can only track one coord system at a time, so moving camera, but not also moving object.  C4d does both but needs help.

Comment: OH, wait a minute.  I misunderstood you.  If all you're trying to do is anonymize someone's face by blurring it out, you don't need 3D tracking at all, 2D tracking is fine.  You don't need dots or markers.  Premiere and Resolve would work fine.  But if that's what you want to do, I'm confused about your original question.  What does "arm cast" mean?  Like a plaster cast for a broken arm?  What does that have to do with "real aim is a face blurring mask"?

Comment: the difference is wearing a marker device that covers the area that we want edited, but in an automatic way (thus wearing it) so that that editor automatically knows what to do whenever the device appears on screen, rather than 2d motion tracking in an editor.